# WiFi & Bluetooth Issues - MSI

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bios, bluetooth

I am using a MSI GF65 Thin, few months back Windows refused to recognise the Network card. I talked to the customer chat support on Windows they asked to talk to me to Manufacturer. The manufacturer straight said that it is a hardware issue and I need to change my network card. The problem is - sometimes while just using the system, **Wi-Fi and Bluetooth stopped working**, and I found a temporary solution - Restart the Laptop into BIOS, and Load the optimal settings, well it works for some time, maybe a day. and then again the same problem happens. \

Anybody have an Idea as to how to solve it? I did check MSI's website, they do have an updated BIOS there, I was unsure whether I should update my BIOS as the chat support on MSI advised me against this.

My English is not so good. Thank you for bearing.

Comment: If you kind of know what you are doing updating the FW looks like a good idea.

Comment: Hi, I did update my BIOS and Firmware, it did work for quiet sometime, again it started doing the same thing.